# Binding unicode λ symbol (code+glyph) to key combination

Tags: keyboard, unicode, xkb

I would like to type Unicode λ in a clear way (key L and alt modifier, for example) and not pressing SHIFT+CTRL+u03bb each time (or doing a poor trick like copy/paste).

I've tried a lot of ways to achieve this (xmodmap, compose and others...), but without success.  By the way, I'm using Linux (Debian 10).

Without a direct help, I'm sure I will not accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, windows has a 3rd party program called autohotkeys, .. I looked to see if linux does and it has something called autokeys e.g.  https://packages.debian.org/unstable/autokey-common

Comment: There are also additional keyboard layouts for Ubuntu, and, I assume, for generic Debian so you could add a Greek keyboard layout. There's a keyboard shortcut for switching layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Compose Key

The following appropriates your right Alt key (assuming your layout possesses one) for what is called a [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key):

```
setxkbmap -option compose:ralt
```

There is Debian documentation for this facility [here](https://wiki.debian.org/XCompose). By default, the key bindings are read from `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (for `en_US` locale, change as needed otherwise), but can be overridden in `~/.XCompose`.

My default Compose file does not possess a key binding for lambda that uses the Compose key (`<Multi_key>`) — only for using `<dead_greek>`, which presumably you do not possess. So create one yourself:

```
cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose # etc.
cat >> ~/.XCompose <<EOF
<Multi_key> <asterisk> <l>              : "λ"   U03BB           # GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA
EOF
```

Compose keys are mediated by X11 clients, so IIRC all you need to do is restart the affected application. Wayland honors them too.

So start a new app and press `<right_alt> * l` and you should see a λ pop up like it just did for me.

The default Compose file is actually kind of barren; there are various git projects trying to assemble more comprehensive ones ([example](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose)). I forget where I pulled mine from, sorry.

Comment: The great obstacle was to notice that there was no key bound to compose mode. In pratice way, this command was the crucial point:   setxkbmap -option compose:ralt

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Curiously,  pressing <right_alt> <*> <l> , but <right_alt> <g> <l>!